# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.version', pip install scipy and pip3 install scipy are successful, but the error persists

Tags: scipy

[image]

```
(base) C:\Users\dadas>pip3 install scipy
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\users\dadas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (1.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in c:\users\dadas\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from scipy) (1.19.1)

(base) C:\Users\dadas>pip install scipy
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scipy) (1.18.1)

(base) C:\Users\dadas>python
Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 138, in <module>
    from scipy.version import version as __version__
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy.version'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand, you have installed python 3.8 and when you run pip3 or pip it goes to this install.

Nevertheless you also have Python 3.7.6 installed which seems to be your base python (when you run python this is this version that is running).

Try to run this code from the command:

```
python -m pip install scipy
```